Troubleshooting Code to Reference and Process Multiple Text Files: Issue with Saving Changes
I wrote this part of the code to reference different files. The sequence is to open the file, run the code, and move on to the next one by referencing the name set up as 'math'. It should do this until all the files with the listed name in the workbook finish, but that doesn't happen. The code opens the file, runs the code (apparently), but doesn't save the changes that the code is supposed to make. And I don't know how to fix it.
Some details, these files are in .txt format and I just want to exclude quotation marks. I already did that, but I can apply it using automation to all files in the folder.
dim pathfile as string
dim pathway as workbook
dim localcode as string
dim wb as workbook
dim wayfile as string
dim i as integer

application.screenupdating = false
application.displayalerts = false

wayfile = "pathfile"

set wb = workbooks.open(wayfile)

range ("A1").Select

i = 1

do while not isempty(range("a" & i))

math = activecell

pathfile = "pathfile"

pathfile = replace(pathfile, "math", math)

set pathway = workbooks.open(pathfile)


'rest of the code-------------


pathway,saveas fileformat:=xlTextWindows

pathway.close

set wb = workbooks.open(camin)

range("A1").Select

activecell.offset(1,0).select

i = i + 1

loop

application.screenupdating = true
application.displayalerts = true

wb.close

msgbox "ok"

I was expecting to create a mode that I could run code through all the files inside a paste to not have to work to open every single .txt file to run the code.

Does this answer your question? Loop doesn't clean the quotation marks Have you tried the code from @Siddharth Rout?

His code clean but i dont get yet how to properly loop through a list of files

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator
